# Your best sound of 2011.

Tags: best, 2011

I did this last year and it was great fun to hear what people had done. So I thought I'd do it again for this year.

The idea is to pick your favorite sound that you recorded during 2011 and share it with your fellow sound recordists in this thread, whether it be a soundfile (maybe on SoundCloud) or a video (Youtube, Vimeo). Help here: https://sound.stackexchange.com/help

All sounds are welcome, whether it's Sound Effect, Ambience, Synth, Music or Speech.

--

Personally, I've been incredibly busy working on TV docs and short films this year, so not alot of time for going out and recording sounds. But here is one that I recorded very early in the year.

I was out at Midnight in January and stopped off a small village church yard and recorded this gloomy sound church bell. Hope you like it:

[youtube]IYr0EizRUhI[/youtube]

Note: I may end up making a blog post on this which will include may favourite sounds I make, so will link to everybodies blogs or websites as a credit.

Answer (score 1):

It's been an exciting year for me as I've really developed my knowledge of DSP and general sound synthesis techniques. I've been working on a new synth aimed at sound designers, and for many reasons it's sounds are my favorite thing this year. The project is still in it's infancy, so I'll not go into details yet, but it's a hybrid physical modelling/FM/wavetable design currently built in Max/Msp. Incidentially, this is the first thing I've built with the new 64-bit audio engine of Max 6 and I'm really pleased with the overall sound quality.

This demonstration soundscape is actually a combination of about four different takes recorded direct from the synth. These we're then assembled in a sequencer, but with no extra effects or dynamics processing, so this is essentially raw sound.

[soundcloud]mark-durham/prototype[/soundcloud]

direct link:

http://soundcloud.com/mark-durham/prototype

Any thoughts or constructive criticism welcome.

Comment: That sounds amazing! REally eerie. Well done.